# Expected value of different dice roll results given number of rolls

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value, poisson-distribution

> A die is rolled $N$ times where $N\sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$. $X =$ number of different results in the rolls. For example: $(1,1,6,1)$ has 2 different results and $(1,2,3,4)$ has 4. Calculate $E(X)$

Define an indicator: $$I_i = \begin{cases} 1,  & \text{$i$ was rolled at least once out of $n$ rolls} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
Then: $$X = \sum_{i=1}^{6} I_i$$
 $$P(I_i = 1 \mid N=n) = 1 - \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n$$
 $$E(X) = E(E(X\mid N)) = E\left(E\left(\sum_{i=1}^6 I_i\mid N\right)\right) = E\left(6\left(1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^N\right)\right) \\ = 6-6E\left(\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^N\right)$$
$$ = 6 - 6\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n\left(\frac{e^{-\lambda} (\lambda)^n}{n!}\right)\right] = 6 - 6\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{e^{-\frac{5}{6}\lambda}\left(\frac{5}{6}\lambda\right)^n}{n!} \right) e^{-\frac{1}{6}}\right] = 6-6e^{-\frac{1}{6}} = 0.92$$

where the last line is the sum of all probabilities of a random variable $Y\sim \operatorname{Pois}(\frac{5}{6}\lambda)$, which sums up to $1.$

This is an odd result since it didn't depend on $\lambda$ and it's too small as is.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: The mistake is in the last line. It's not clear to me what you tried to do there. Can you explain the steps?

Comment: Yes, i forgot to remove the fraction, i've edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that $\mathrm e^{-\lambda}\ne\mathrm e^{-\frac56\lambda}\mathrm e^{-\frac16}$.